# Creating an SSL keystore for bitbucket server

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, keystore

I'm getting quite frustrated trying to setup https access to our bitbucket server.

Following bitbuckets [documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/securing-bitbucket-server-with-tomcat-using-ssl-776640127.html) isn't that helpful.

So far I have the executed the following commands

Firtly, I created a certificate signing request and sent that to my certificate provider and they have sent me a certificate.

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout domain.key -out domain.csr
```

At this point I have 3 files, domain.key, domain.csr and a ssl certificate provided to mey, domain.cer

I then tried to create a keystore with the following command

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore ssl-keystore
```

I was prompted for a keystore password and I provided one.

I then tried to import the certificate provided to me.

```
keytool -import -alias tomcat -file domain.cer -keystore ssl-keystore
```

and got the following error.

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Public keys in reply and keystore don't match
```

I'm a complete ssl newbie and am relying on following website instructions and am at a loss now what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have 2 files below `domain.key` and `domain.cer` (private key and signed certificate) you can change tho format to `pkcs12` like this

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in domain.cer -inkey domain.key -name domain -out domain.p12
```

and then import in `jkl` with

```
keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass changeme1 -destkeystore domain.jks -srcstorepass changeme2 -srckeystore domain.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12
```

where `changeme1` is the new keystore password and `changeme2` is the password specified during the export (first step)

now you can use `domain.jks`

Comment: I tried what you said and unfortunately, my bitbucket server fails with jsse.alias_no_key_entry.

Comment: Fantastic!!!! I worked out what was the problem. The "-name domain" you mentioned in your answer should be "-name tomcat" as this is what bitbucket was looking for. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: yes this is the alias to lookup key/crt in keystore. You welcome